# Uri Segment When Using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, uri

In my codeigniter application i want to display the uri segments.Iam using ajax to call controller.
This is my html code

```
function add_store(){
            var path="<?php echo base_url()?>images/loader.gif";
            $("#add_store").html("<div align='center' style='margin-top:200px;'><img src="+path+" style='width:25px;' /></div>").show();
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Admin/add_store/",
                success: function(msg){
                $("#add_store").html('');
                $("#add_store").html(msg).show();
                }  
            });
}
```

This is my controller code

```
public function add_store()
    {
        echo $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
```

nothing will be displayed.How can i get uri segments?
If i use

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);
```

Then it displays `Admin` but after 1 nothing will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your controller 'Admin' is calling a method 'add_store', but there are no further segments, that's why your 3rd one isn't passed.

> 1st segment: "Admin"
>
> 2nd segment: "add_store"

I don't know what you want to achieve, but if you have an url like:

```
admin/add_store/someparam/someotherparam
```

you would just do

```
public function add_store($param1, $param2)
{
    echo $param1; // 'someparam'
    echo $param2; // 'someotherparam'
}
```

without the need to call directly the uri segment.

Comment: if you create a `base` tag inside your html head element you can call `base_url()` there and avoid having to echo it in your JavaScript

Comment: dude, i would have never thought about that. Good looking out. That is a great way to keep Codeigniter features in one place instead of using php and being able to use php vars in javascript files. would have never thought to just create meta tags for page vars like the base_url(). Im always calling jscript files or controllers etc and always just do the /full/url/to/function now i can still use my environments and have an absolute url to ajax calls. Thanks a million on this...if i could do 100 upvotes i would.